# Halide Jit compilation

Tags: c++, image, halide

Im trying to compile my halide program to jit to use it later in code few times on different images. But i think i making something wrong, can anyone correct me?
First I create halide function to run:

```
void m_gammaFunctionTMOGenerate()
{
    Halide::ImageParam img(Halide::type_of<float>(), 3);
    img.set_stride(0, 4);
    img.set_stride(2, 1);
    Halide::Var x, y, c;
    Halide::Param<float> key, sat, clampMax, clampMin;
    Halide::Param<bool> cS;
    Halide::Func gamma;
    // algorytm
    //img.width() , img.height();
    if (cS.get())
    {
        float k1 = 1.6774;
        float k2 = 0.9925;
        sat.set((1 + k1) * pow(key.get(), k2) / (1 + k1 * pow(key.get(), k2)));
    }
    Halide::Expr luminance = img(x, y, 0) * 0.072186f + img(x, y, 1) * 0.715158f + img(x, y, 2) *  0.212656f;
    Halide::Expr ldr_lum = (luminance - clampMin) / (clampMax - clampMin);
    Halide::clamp(ldr_lum, 0.f, 1.f);
    ldr_lum = Halide::pow(ldr_lum, key);
    Halide::Expr imLum = img(x, y, c) / luminance;
    imLum = Halide::pow(imLum, sat) * ldr_lum;
    Halide::clamp(imLum, 0.f, 1.f);
    gamma(x, y, c) = imLum;
    // rozkład
    gamma.vectorize(x, 16).parallel(y);

    // kompilacja
    auto & obuff = gamma.output_buffer();
    obuff.set_stride(0, 4);
    obuff.set_stride(2, 1);
    obuff.set_extent(2, 3);
    std::vector<Halide::Argument> arguments = { img, key, sat, clampMax, clampMin, cS };
    m_gammaFunction = (gammafunction)(gamma.compile_jit());

}
```

store it in pointer:

```
typedef int(*gammafunction)(buffer_t*, float, float, float, float, bool, buffer_t*);
gammafunction m_gammaFunction;
```

then i try to run it:

```
buffer_t  output_buf = { 0 };
//// The host pointers point to the start of the image data:
buffer_t buf = { 0 };
buf.host = (uint8_t *)data; // Might also need const_cast
float * output = new float[width * height * 4];
output_buf.host = (uint8_t*)(output);
//                                // If the buffer doesn't start at (0, 0), then assign mins
output_buf.extent[0] = buf.extent[0] = width; // In elements, not bytes
output_buf.extent[1] = buf.extent[1] = height; // In elements, not bytes
output_buf.extent[2] = buf.extent[2] = 4;    // Assuming RGBA
//                 // No need to assign additional extents as they were init'ed to zero above
output_buf.stride[0] = buf.stride[0] = 4; // RGBA interleaved
output_buf.stride[1] = buf.stride[1] = width * 4; // Assuming no line padding
output_buf.stride[2] = buf.stride[2] = 1; // Channel interleaved
output_buf.elem_size = buf.elem_size = sizeof(float);

// Run the pipeline
int error = m_photoFunction(&buf, params[0], &output_buf);
```

But it doesn't work...
Error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x000002974F552DE0 in Viewer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x000002974F552DE0.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Edit:

Here is my code for running function:

```
buffer_t  output_buf = { 0 };
//// The host pointers point to the start of the image data:
buffer_t buf = { 0 };
buf.host = (uint8_t *)data; // Might also need const_cast
float * output = new float[width * height * 4];
output_buf.host = (uint8_t*)(output);
//                                // If the buffer doesn't start at (0, 0), then assign mins
output_buf.extent[0] = buf.extent[0] = width; // In elements, not bytes
output_buf.extent[1] = buf.extent[1] = height; // In elements, not bytes
output_buf.extent[2] = buf.extent[2] = 3;    // Assuming RGBA
                                             //                // No need to assign additional extents as they were init'ed to zero above
output_buf.stride[0] = buf.stride[0] = 4; // RGBA interleaved
output_buf.stride[1] = buf.stride[1] = width * 4; // Assuming no line padding
output_buf.stride[2] = buf.stride[2] = 1; // Channel interleaved
output_buf.elem_size = buf.elem_size = sizeof(float);

// Run the pipeline
int error = m_gammaFunction(&buf, params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3], params[4] > 0.5 ? true : false, &output_buf);

if (error) {
    printf("Halide returned an error: %d\n", error);
    return -1;
}

memcpy(output, data, size * sizeof(float));
```

can anyone help me with it?

**Edit:**

Thanks to @KhouriGiordano I found out what I was doing wrong. Indeed I switched from AOT compiling to this code. So now my code looks like that:

```
class GammaOperator
{
public:
    GammaOperator();

    int realize(buffer_t * input, float params[], buffer_t * output, int width);
private:

    HalideFloat m_key;
    HalideFloat m_sat;
    HalideFloat m_clampMax;
    HalideFloat m_clampMin;
    HalideBool  m_cS;

    Halide::ImageParam m_img;
    Halide::Var x, y, c;
    Halide::Func m_gamma;
};


GammaOperator::GammaOperator()
    : m_img( Halide::type_of<float>(), 3)
{

    Halide::Expr w = (1.f + 1.6774f) * pow(m_key.get(), 0.9925f) / (1.f + 1.6774f * pow(m_key.get(), 0.9925f));
    Halide::Expr sat = Halide::select(m_cS, m_sat, w);

    Halide::Expr luminance = m_img(x, y, 0) * 0.072186f + m_img(x, y, 1) * 0.715158f + m_img(x, y, 2) *  0.212656f;
    Halide::Expr ldr_lum = (luminance - m_clampMin) / (m_clampMax - m_clampMin);
    ldr_lum = Halide::clamp(ldr_lum, 0.f, 1.f);
    ldr_lum = Halide::pow(ldr_lum, m_key);
    Halide::Expr imLum = m_img(x, y, c) / luminance;
    imLum = Halide::pow(imLum, sat) * ldr_lum;
    imLum = Halide::clamp(imLum, 0.f, 1.f);
    m_gamma(x, y, c) = imLum;

}

int GammaOperator::realize(buffer_t * input, float params[], buffer_t * output, int width)
{
    m_img.set(Halide::Buffer(Halide::type_of<float>(), input));
    m_img.set_stride(0, 4);
    m_img.set_stride(1, width * 4);
    m_img.set_stride(2, 4);
    // algorytm
    m_gamma.vectorize(x, 16).parallel(y);

    //params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3], params[4] > 0.5 ? true : false
    //{ img, key, sat, clampMax, clampMin, cS };
    m_key.set(params[0]);
    m_sat.set(params[1]);
    m_clampMax.set(params[2]);
    m_clampMin.set(params[3]);
    m_cS.set(params[4] > 0.5f ? true : false);
    //// kompilacja
    m_gamma.realize(Halide::Buffer(Halide::type_of<float>(), output));
    return 0;
}
```

and i use it like that:

```
buffer_t  output_buf = { 0 };
    //// The host pointers point to the start of the image data:
    buffer_t buf = { 0 };
    buf.host = (uint8_t *)data; // Might also need const_cast
    float * output = new float[width * height * 4];
    output_buf.host = (uint8_t*)(output);
    //                                // If the buffer doesn't start at (0, 0), then assign mins
    output_buf.extent[0] = buf.extent[0] = width; // In elements, not bytes
    output_buf.extent[1] = buf.extent[1] = height; // In elements, not bytes
    output_buf.extent[2] = buf.extent[2] = 4;    // Assuming RGBA
                                                 //                // No need to assign additional extents as they were init'ed to zero above
    output_buf.stride[0] = buf.stride[0] = 4; // RGBA interleaved
    output_buf.stride[1] = buf.stride[1] = width * 4; // Assuming no line padding
    output_buf.stride[2] = buf.stride[2] = 1; // Channel interleaved
    output_buf.elem_size = buf.elem_size = sizeof(float);

    // Run the pipeline

    int error = s_gamma->realize(&buf, params, &output_buf, width);
```

but it is still crashing on m_gamma.realize function with info in console:

```
Error: Constraint violated: f0.stride.0 (4) == 1 (1)
```

Comment: All `ImageParam` start with an implicit `set_stride(0,1)`. The `set_min()`, `set_extent()` and `set_stride()` member functions are constraints that must be met by any buffer passed in. It allows the code generation to hard code those values. Use `set_stride(0,4)` to match what you are doing or `set_stride(0,Expr())` to remove the constraint.

Comment: Also, since the min, extent and stride that you set are `Expr`, they can be dependent on `Param` values like width and height.

Comment: I already have it: ' m_img.set_stride(0, 4);' and it doesnt work i think...

Comment: You have `m_img.set_stride(2, 4)`which should be 1. The output also has constraints. Use `m_gamma.output_buffer() .set_extent(...) .set_stride(...)`.

Comment: Ok, now i quite understand that. I set my image and output_buffer extent and strides and it does work. However my images process went wrong. Whole image is processed like it will have only one channel of color. And in output buffer all channels got one value. I set like that:

 `m_img.set_stride(0, 4);
 m_img.set_stride(1, width * 4);
 m_img.set_stride(2, 1);
 m_img.set_extent(0, width);
 m_img.set_extent(1, height);
 m_img.set_extent(2, 4);

 m_gamma.output_buffer().set_stride(0, 4);
 m_gamma.output_buffer().set_stride(1, width * 4);
 m_gamma.output_buffer().set_stride(2, 1);`

Comment: I've lost track of what your code looks like by now. Join me in [a chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122131/halide) and you can post your code on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Halide::Param::get()`, you are extracting the (default of 0) value from the `Param` object at the time you call `get()`. If you want to use the parameter value given at the time you call the generated function, just use it without calling `get` and it should be implicitly converted to an `Expr`.

Since `Param` is not convertible to a boolean, the Halide way of doing an `if` is `Halide::select()`.

You aren't using the clamped return value of `Halide::clamp()`.

I don't see `cS` being used by the Halide code, only the C code.

Now to your JIT problem. It looks like you started doing AOT compilation and switched to JIT.

You make a `std::vector<Halide::Argument>` but don't pass it anywhere. How can Halide know what `Param` you want to use? It looks at the `Func` and finds references to `ImageParam` and `Param` objects.

How can you know what order it expects the `Param`? You have no control over this. I was able to dump the bitcode by defining `HL_GENBITCODE=1` and then view that with `llvm-dis` to see your function:

```
int gamma
    ( buffer_t *img
    , float clampMax
    , float key
    , float clampMin
    , float sat
    , void *user_context
    , buffer_t *result
    );
```

- Use `gamma.realize(Halide::Buffer(Halide::type_of<float>(), &output_buf))` instead of using `gamma.compile_jit()` and trying to call the generated function properly.

For one time use:

- Use `Image` instead of `ImageParam`.
- Use `Expr` instead of `Param`.

For repeated use with a single JIT compile:

- Keep the `ImageParam` and `Param` around and set them before realizing the `Func`.

Comment: Yes, sorry i paste wrong code in second i will edit first post with proper one